# How portable are the works chmod and chown commands?

Tags: permissions

Lets suppose a file is being owned by a user named *mrxyz* with UID and GID 1000, and has RW permissions for the file *(esp. in ext file-systems)*. Now if the file is brought to my system will my user *hash* with UID 1000 inherit the permissions or will I have to make changes to fit my context? So basically, I want to know how changing ownership and permission with `chown` and `chmod` work from portability point of view?

PS. It was a curiosity raised in this comment ["...would there be issues with permissions/ownership if I plugged the disk into another box?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405993/usb-drive-auto-mounted-by-user-but-gets-write-permissions-for-root-only/406550#comment522376_406550) that I posted this Q. *(So, it would be great to have answers covering portability of files as well as filesystem.)*

Comment: What do you use for transport? Also an ext filesystem? `scp` or NFS? Do you use tar (as @Timo suggested)?

Comment: portable USB storages.. actually I was concerned more with how the permissions for normal files (I do use archive files too, when I need to preserve more of the metadatas with my files) would behave across systems in such devices..

Answer (score 7):

It depends on how you bring it to your computer and who and how you extract that file.

In a `.tar` file both the user name and UID are written. If you extract that as yourself, the files get your UID and GID, if you try to extract it as `root` it will try to restore the UID based on the username and failing to find that based on the UID. The permissions are normally influenced by your `umask` when extracting as normal user, not when extracting as `root`. Several commandline options for tar influence that (`--numeric-owner`, `--preserve`, `--same-permissions`).

Other programs like `cpio` have similar behaviour, but of course different commandline options.

Assuming that you extract as yourself (and not as `root`), your current `umask` is probably the defining factor. Try that out and if you have specific problems with your transport mechanism getting things to work, come back and ask (or update the question).

Comment: nice... and please, if you could also include how they would carry with file systems in portable devices..

Comment: @hash it all depends on **how** you intend to move things around, please extend your question with that information (medium, filesystem on medium, direct or tarred/zipped). If you copy a file to FAT without putting it in a tar (or zip or cpio) file, you loose a lot of info.

Comment: it's portable USB storages.. and already stated in the Q with ext filesystem (ext4 to be more precise).. I do get what you've written about `.tar` files, and about the incompatibility of Unix permission with FAT, NTFS systems.. to summarize, it's normal files in `ext4` partitioned USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

Only the UID counts. If `ls -l` shows a file as owned by tstaerk on my computer it may well be hash on your computer. Then you are allowed to modify (in case of rwx------). This is usual not only in ext file systems.